# Linking Ace to a custom theme outside of default theme directory in Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, ace-editor

In my Angular 2 (built with angular-cli) I am trying to link an Ace editor to my custom theme which will be placed within my app's assets folder `src/app/assets` rather than buried in `node_modules`.

In `angular-cli.json` I have:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/ace.js",
    "./assets/my-theme.js"
],
```

But the devtools console spits out a 404 at me:
`GET http://localhost:4200/theme-my-theme.js`

I cannot seem to find a good way to reference it. The error remains the same in that the request looks at localhost:4200, changing only the file name that I am trying to get.

I think I am missing some crucial piece of info on base paths.

Comment: how do you set the ace theme option?

Comment: Initially I used `[theme]="'clouds'"` but I understood that this might not suffice for custom theme locations, so I moved on to `this.editor.setTheme('cloud')` and then tried with various paths.

Answer (score 1):

If ace doesn't know a theme (or mode), then it will try to download or "GET" the file locally from your webserver, that's why you're getting this request: `GET http://localhost:4200/theme-my-theme.js`

The trick is, you need to register your theme with Ace. Look at how the Ace-provided themes work. For instance, theme-monokai.js starts with this line:

```
define("ace/theme/monokai",["require","exports","module","ace/lib/dom"], function(require, exports, module) {
```

That line defines a theme named "monokai".

Comment: Thanks for your input. Do you happen to know how to do that in TypeScript/Webpack? My guess is the AMD style isn't going to work, is it?

Comment: You're right, not AMD. The library [ng2-ace-editor](https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor) integrates Ace with Angular2. I've used it, and it works. To use that library, follow the comments in the README, especially the comments there on how to use theme "eclipse" as an example.

Answer (score -1):

```
ace.config.set('basePath', '/libs/ace');
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.